# SQL return 2 values to C# web service

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services

I have a SQL Stored Procedure that works like this: it updates the Confirmed column in a PaymentRecords table, which has a default value of 0, to be either 1 (approved) or 2 (rejected). To ensure concurrency control, it prevents updates from occurring if the Confirmed value is already 1 or 2.

When the update is successful, it returns a string 'SUCCESS', where as if it fails, it returns the chequeNumber to display a message saying that particular cheque has already been updated. Both of these are returned to a C# web service.

SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateUnverifiedChequeConfirmed] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @id uniqueidentifier,
    @confirmed int,
    @rejectReason nvarchar(MAX),
    @bankName nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @existingConfirmed int;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    SELECT TOP 1 @existingConfirmed = [PaymentRecords].[confirmed] 
    FROM [dbo].[PaymentRecords] 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ChequePayments] 
    ON [ChequePayments].[paymentRecordID] = [PaymentRecords].[id]
    WHERE [ChequePayments].[id] = @id

    IF @existingConfirmed = '1' OR @existingConfirmed = '2'
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Cheque already updated by another user, further changes not allowed.';

            --SELECT 0 AS FAIL
            SELECT [ChequePayments].[chequeNo] AS chequeNo
            FROM [ChequePayments]
            WHERE [ChequePayments].[id] = @id
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [dbo].[PaymentRecords]
            SET confirmed = @confirmed, rejectReason = @rejectReason, [timestamp] = GETDATE()
            FROM [dbo].[PaymentRecords]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[ChequePayments]
            ON [ChequePayments].[paymentRecordID] = [PaymentRecords].[id]
            WHERE [ChequePayments].[id] = @id

            UPDATE [dbo].[ChequePayments]
            SET bankName = @bankName, [timestamp] = GETDATE()
            WHERE [ChequePayments].[id] = @id

            --SELECT 1 AS SUCCESS
            SELECT 'SUCCESS' AS SUCCESS
        END
END
```

C#:

```
unverifiedChequeNumberResponse ICommon.updateUnverifiedCheque(unverifiedChequeRequest request, string id)
        {
            string result, rejectReason;

            Guid newID;

            if (request.bankName == "Select a Bank")
            {
                return new unverifiedChequeNumberResponse("Error: No bank selected.");
            }

            if (request.rejectReason == "")
            {
                rejectReason = null;
            }
            else
            {
                rejectReason = request.rejectReason;
            }

            if (Guid.TryParse(id, out newID))
            {
                try
                {
                    result = dbkl.UpdateUnverifiedChequeConfirmed(newID, request.confirmed, rejectReason, request.bankName).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (isDebug() == true)
                    {
                        return new unverifiedChequeNumberResponse(ex.Message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new unverifiedChequeNumberResponse("Error: Database inaccessible");
                    }
                }

                if (result == "SUCCESS")
                {
                    return new unverifiedChequeNumberResponse();
                }
                else
                {
                    unverifiedChequeNumberResponse response = new unverifiedChequeNumberResponse();
                    response.chequeNo = result;
                    return new unverifiedChequeNumberResponse("Error: Cheque " + response.chequeNo + " already updated by another user.");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                return new unverifiedChequeNumberResponse("Error: Invalid ID.");
            }
        }
```

Although all of this is working properly, I need to make a change so that the SP returns a 1 when successful and 0 when unsuccessful. The two issues I am facing are:

1. How to make the unsuccessful update path in the SP return 2 values, namely 0 and the chequeNumber? If I write it as:

   SELECT 0 AS FAIL, [ChequePayments].[chequeNo] AS chequeNo
   FROM [ChequePayments]
   WHERE [ChequePayments].[id] = @id

it ends up returning a null value and throws an exception.

2. If the chequeNumber has a value of 1 (unlikely in practice but still worth covering) and the update is denied, the web service will still return the success message. Is there a way to change it so that the service can differentiate between 1 as a chequeNumber and 1 as a Success value?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using SQL [Output parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx). For example;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateUnverifiedChequeConfirmed] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @id uniqueidentifier,
    @confirmed int,
    @rejectReason nvarchar(MAX),
    @bankName nvarchar(MAX),
    @result1 int output,
    @result2 varchar(50) output
AS
BEGIN

    -- do stuff...

    set @result1 = 123
    set @result2 = 'success'

END
```

You would have to update your .Net code to define the output paramaters then read their values after the call.

You might also want to consider using transactions for concurrency control - that's what they're for, and they will provide a more robust solution than you have here.